# Why zh-hans no working in localizer of blazor webassembly?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I followed the sample project in https://github.com/pranavkm/LocSample

Here is the code of Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Temple
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
            builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

            var host = builder.Build();
            var localStorage = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILocalStorageService>();
            string CurrentLanguage=await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("Language");           
            Debug.WriteLine(CurrentLanguage);            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentLanguage))
            {
                var culture = new CultureInfo(CurrentLanguage);
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
            }
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code of index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@inject IStringLocalizer<Index> Localizer;
@inject NavigationManager Nav
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage

<h1>@Localizer["Test"]</h1>

<button @onclick="ABC">123123</button>
Welcome to your new app.

@code{
    public void ABC()
    {        
        localStorage.SetItemAsync("Language", "zh-Hans");        
        Nav.NavigateTo(Nav.Uri, forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```

And here is the file list:
[image]

As you see, I have using the `Blazored.LocalStorage` nuget package to achieve the local storage and it works well.

The problem is when I clicked the button in index.razor. The language never changes to Chinese.

What's more, I found a strange problem. After I modified the code in `index.razor` like this:

```
@code{
    public void ABC()
    {        
        localStorage.SetItemAsync("Language", "en");        
        Nav.NavigateTo(Nav.Uri, forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```

When I clicked the button, it changed the language to English correctly.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Did it really "change" the language to _en_?  From what?

Comment: What doest that Debug.WriteLine(CurrentLanguage);   tell you?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, it changed. I set the English value of the Key 'Test' is "123123" and the Chinese value of the Key 'Test' is "55555". It showed "123123" correctly.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The Debug.WriteLine(CurrentLanguage); is used to check whether the local storage works well. It showed zh-hans when I clicked it. After I modified the code, it showed en.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

In asp.net core the language name can be 'zh-hans' or 'zh-Hans' while in Blazor in can only be 'zh-Hans'. It is case sensitivity in Blazor.